# Hibernate incompatible data type in conversion for Enum

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a class with an enumerated attribute which I would like to query on. I'm using the Spring JPA native query of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM object WHERE object.type in ?1
```

where parameter 1 is a `List<Type>`.

The attribute is set as follows using hibernate:

```
@Column(name = "type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Type type;
```

The underlying database is MySQL where the field is of type `varchar(255)`.

When I try and execute the query I get `SQLGrammar Exception: could not execute query`; `SQL Error: -5561, SQLState: 42561, incompatible data type in conversion`.

I've tried setting the `EnumType` to `ORDINAL` with no noticeable effect and I've tried querying directly with a `List<String>` instead where I got errors trying to convert from `String` to `Object.Type`

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I've written a query with both a `List<String>` and a `List<Type>` check and the error comes back with could not execute query;

```
SQL [SELECT * FROM object WHERE object.string in (?, ?) AND object.type in (?)];
```

Comment: Can you add the whole stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I'd have to manually type that in here... it's big, I can write out the first line if that helps

Comment: Hmm. Why can't you just copy paste the thing?